# Sending pandas dataframe to java application

Tags: java, python, pandas, numpy, jython

I have created a python script for predictive analytics using pandas,numpy etc. I want to send my result set to java application . Is their simple way to do it. I found we can use Jython for java python integration but it doesn't use many data analysis libraries. Any help will be great . Thank you .

Comment: This question is a bit broad when you send what do you mean? Could you pipe the result as a csv or you're asking to send some binary representation between different applications?

Comment: I just want some readable data ( in this case predicted values ) to pass to java application. I was thinking if I could call java object/function and transfer data to it. Creating CSV is an option but i fear it might make whole process time consuming ( and not prefered way as it could lead to multiple issues in future).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using xml to transfer the data between the two applications ? 
My next suggestion would be to output the data in JSON format in a txt file and then call the java application which will read the JSON from the text file.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Michael. I will see if transfering data through xml is fast and easy.

Answer (score 0):

Better approach here is to use java pipe input like `python pythonApp.py | java read`. Output of python application can be used as an input for java application till the format of data is consitent and known. Above soultions of creating a file and then reading also works but is prone to more errors.